# Visit mobile version of site (Via webview), working sometimes

Tags: android, android-webview

I've written this app to visit a webpage.
I've implemented a setting to choose whether to access the mobile version or the desktop version of the site (I know it's a dirty hack to set User agent).

It works fine on my galaxy tab 2 but it doesn't on my Xperia S. And I can't figure out why..

```
link = getIntent().getExtras().getString("link");
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);


    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
        }
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);  
    if(settings.getString("user_agent", "Mobil").equals("Mobil")){
        link = link.substring(24);
        link = "http://mobilsiden.mobi"+link;
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Nexus 7 Build/JRO03D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Safari/535.19");
    }else{
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20120427 Firefox/15.0a1");
    }

    webView.loadUrl(link);
```

Is there a more nice solution than changing User Agent (I can't think of any)? And can anyone see why it might work on one device, but not the other?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually the webPage should handle what version of the site to display based on the device calling it. You should not implement this functionality by your own. See e.g. the engadget website, open engadget.com form mobile and you will get automatically the mobile version.

Comment: I know it's based on the device calling it.. 

But I need functionality to override this behavior.